# multiple movieclips and one class linkage ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

MovieClip Aries has a "AS Linkage" class of Aries.
MovieClip Zeus has a "AS Linkage" class of Zeus.
MovieClip Maze Runner has a "AS Linkage" class of MazeRunner.
and a Hero class.

MazeRunner class adds hero into stage.

```
package
{   
    public class MazeRunner extends MovieClip
    {
        private var _hero           :Hero;

        public function MazeRunner():void
        {
            if(stage == null)
            {
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init, false, 0, true);
                addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, clean, false, 0, true);
            }
            else
            {
                init();
            }
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void
        {
            _hero = new Hero;
            addChild(_hero);
        }
    }
}
```

I want "Hero" class to be connected/associated to both "Aries" or "Zeus" MovieClip class so that either movieclips can be added on the stage when i choose between them before MazeRunner add it to the stage. is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest passing a parameter when instantiating your hero class.

For example:

```
_hero = new Hero("Zeus");
```

And then in your Hero class, you'd just have to instantiate a movieclip using a switch statement:

```
switch (selectedCharacter){

case "Zeus":
_hero.addChild(Zeus);
break;

case "Aries":
_hero.addChild(Aries); 
break;
}
```

Sorry, I'm a bit rusty with as3. I assume Zeus or Aries will contain the images/properties of that character. This will, in theory, attach your character to the _hero movieclip. You can then have access to all of Aries'/Zeus' methods/properties by using _hero.Aries.whateverFunction(). Hope this steers you in the right direction.

Comment: i can understand if your AS3 is a bit rusty. its not a very "in demand" kinda language lol. anyway thanks a lot! gonna try and use your method and hope it works. will update if anything comes up. Thanks again and have a great day!

Comment: Call to a possibly undefined method addChild through a reference with static type String on code `_hero.addChild(Zeus);` why is that?

Comment: Those were just some examples. Essentially you'd want to create a movieclip with the corresponding classes 

    var zeus_mc = new Zeus();

then if "Zeus" is the string in the selected character, use    

    _hero.addChild(zeus_mc) 

That zeus movieclip will then be a child to the hero container. Hope this helps but my previous post was more of a step in the right direction than accurate code.

Comment: your idea worked! but now the problem is that my code for checking what `_hero.currentFrame` has stopped working because i think `_hero` simply added the movieclips but didn't inherit it? sorry can't paste code to show what im talking about cause it's too long.

Comment: I think you can access it with this var currFrame = _hero.zeus_mc.currentFrame();

Comment: question, why is `_hero.addChild(Zeus);` inside `Hero` class?

Comment: _hero.addChild(Zeus) does not need to be inside of the Hero class, it simply appends the Zeus movieclip to the _hero movieclip.
Think of _hero being a container and when the user selects the character, the character is added into the hero container. In this case, the container is actually just an empty movieclip and you're adding the zeus movieclip to it.